# Atomic operation to read line from file & remove it

Tags: bash, sed

I have dozens of numerical physics simulations which need to be run, but if I try to run more than about 5 simultaneously, my use of server resources becomes too great and the processes are unceremoniously (and uncontrollably by me) killed off.

Proposed solution: create some kind of 'to-do list' file containing a line's worth of instructions for every simulation to be run (i.e. the path to the simulation executable which must be called). Then, start up five scripts (or more/fewer, depending on resources available). Each then 'bites off' one line of the schedule, starts up the corresponding simulation process, and comes back to the schedule after the simulation has exited.

With my present knowledge of bash scripting, this all sounds very doable - e.g. `head -n1 schedule` to get the next instruction in line, followed by `sed -i "1d" schedule` to clear it from the list - *except* for the issue of race conditions. I'm afraid that two processes might read out *the same* instruction before the first one gets around to deleting it from the list.

I've been thinking of all sorts of possible workarounds or safety measures, but they get complicated very fast and I simply have no experience dealing with this. Ideally, I'd like a solution that allows a single command to *both* edit the schedule file in-place to delete the line *and* prints the deleted line to `stdout` so that the script can go on to do something with it.

Comment: One easy way to solve the atomic part is to only have _one_ process reading the file and let that process spawn _max_ processes. When one process dies and if the main process still has work in the to-do list, spawn a new process.

Comment: I would definitely go with @TedLyngmo's suggestion here, but you can easily do what you ask with `flock`

Comment: I've performed this type of operations hundreds of times using one of the following: **a)** if I have access to a database I put the list of instructions into a table (along with start/stop/status columns) and via (SQL) update statements and exclusive (row) locks have each process 'check out' a single item from the list ... **b)** in a shell environment I create a separate file for each task and via `find` and `flock` ensure each process can only read/process a given file at a time

Comment: `sed -i` doesn't edit the file in-place, it uses a temp file behind the scenes. Ditto for `perl -i`, `awk -i inplace`, etc. If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output plus what you've tried so far then we can try to help you. See [ask]/

Comment: Use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).